How does an engine work?
This might be a stupid question, and it's not so much about how the engine works - it's moreso a question about, why does the engine stall? Everyone and their dog knows what an engine stall is and what it feels like, but I want to know what's actually happening, and why the engine can't function at a lower rpm in petrol/diesel cars, in contrast to how steam engines could function at extremely low rpm. Just looking for a simple answer for a simple person on why engines stall.
Thanks!
:)

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Also see this question
